# In awk, how to find the maximum of floats in column Y for each distinct element in column X

Tags: comparison, awk, numbers

If column Y contains only positive values, the following awk command works fine:

```
$ echo -e "g1 2\ng1 3\ng2 4\ng2 1\ng3 1" > input_pos.txt
$ cat input_pos.txt
g1 2
g1 3
g2 4
g2 1
g3 1
$ awk '{if(! $1 in a)a[$1]=$2; else if($2 > a[$1])a[$1]=$2} END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' input_pos.txt
g1 3
g2 4
g3 1
```

It works also well as long as there is at least one positive number:

```
$ echo -e "g1 2\ng1 -3\ng2 4\ng2 1\ng3 1" > input_pos-neg.txt
$ cat input_pos-neg.txt
g1 2
g1 -3
g2 4
g2 1
g3 1
$ awk '{if(! $1 in a)a[$1]=$2; else if($2 > a[$1])a[$1]=$2} END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' input_pos-neg.txt
g1 2
g2 4
g3 1
```

However, it doesn't work when there are only negative numbers:

```
$ echo -e "g1 -2\ng1 -3\ng2 -4\ng2 -1\ng3 -1" > input_neg.txt
$ cat input_neg.txt
g1 -2
g1 -3
g2 -4
g2 -1
g3 -1
$ awk '{if(! $1 in a)a[$1]=$2; else if($2 > a[$1])a[$1]=$2} END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' input_neg.txt
g1
g2
g3
```

Idem in this example:

```
$ echo -e "g1 -2\ng1 -3\ng2 4\ng2 1\ng3 1" > input_neg2.txt
$ cat input_neg2.txt
g1 -2
g1 -3
g2 4
g2 1
g3 1
$ awk '{if(! $1 in a)a[$1]=$2; else if($2 > a[$1])a[$1]=$2} END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' input_neg2.txt
g1
g2 4
g3 1
```

I looked at the gawk manual ([Conversions of strings and numbers](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Conversion)), and I tried to add a +0 to $2 to force the > comparison to be performed as numeric, but still can't find a solution to my problem. Any idea is welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `!` operator ties harder than `in`, thus if you parenthesize `(! $1 in a)`, i.e. `(! ($1 in a))` it works.